# simple delayed shutdown app in ANSI C, also switch acting weird

Tags: c

At the beginning i wanted to point out the fact, that I'm a complete beginner with C and programming. I'm trying to make some simple console app to schedule delayed shutdown of my PC.
Here's my code:

```
   int main()
{
   int  minutes, seconds;
   char command[50];
   char sa;

   printf("(s)hutdown or (a)bort?. 0 to exit.\n");
   scanf("%c", &sa);
   switch (sa)
   {
   case 's':
      printf("How many minutes till shutdown\n");
      scanf("%d\n", &minutes);
      seconds = minutes * 60;
      sprintf(command, "shutdown /s /f /t %d\n", seconds);
      system(command);
      system("exit");

   case 'a':
      sprintf(command, "shutdown /a");
      system(command);
      system("exit");

   default:
      printf("Bad choice.");
      system("exit");
   }

   return 0;
}
```

My problems are: 
1. When I choose 's', and after writing down appropriate amount of minutes and pressing enter `system('exit')` should close the console, but that doesn't work. I have to write down anything to get it closed. And even after that case 'a' is being executed anyway, cancelling any delayed shutdown.

2. After choosing 's' or 'a' the default case is executed as well. So the output I get always ends with "Bad choice."

Could somebody help me out with my (probably stupid) problem? Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: after delayed shutdown, add sleep.

Comment: First of all [the `system` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/277bwbdz.aspx) doesn't work as you expect it to. Secondly `switch` cases needs a `break` to end it.

Comment: I totally forgot about breaks. But still, after choosing 'a' console closes itself, but after choosing 's' waits for any other input to close itself.

Comment: You would not need breaks if you called the `exit()` function instead of `system("exit")`.  Whether that by itself will result in the console closing depends on how the console was opened in the first place, however.

Comment: Adding exit(0) at the end doesn't change anything... The program is simple executable under Windows.

Comment: found the solution: after changing %d to %f it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system function starts a new shell, so

```
system("exit");
```

will just exit from that new shell, returning execution control back to your program.

To kill the parent shell you can probably send it a SIGHUP signal.